# MySQL stored procedure returns results on first run only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

[Picture of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOUKU.png)

My stored procedure will successfully run the first time it is called (whether through an api or the MySQL Workbench) but the second or nth time after the first, 0 row(s) are returned.

What causes this behavior?

json_table?

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `graphs_characters_rank_bar`()
BEGIN
select
    x.*
from
    players p
    ,json_table(p.character_ranks, "$[*]" columns(
        rowid for ordinality
        ,`character` varchar(255) path "$.character" default '0' on error default '0' on empty
        ,`rank` int(11) path "$.rank" default '0' on error default '0' on empty
        )
    ) x
where
    p.id = 1
order by
    x.`rank` desc;
END
```

the players table looks like this

| `id` | `name`   | `character_ranks`                  |

| `1`  | `MyName` | `[{"rank": 930, "character": 12}]` |

Comment: Could you please provide a sanitized sample of your data?

Comment: made an edit to post,
character_ranks has a json datatype in mysql 8

Comment: in my 8.0.17 Database i run your stored procedure 10 times and it shows every time the same result. Eventuella an update could help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems an bug when **const** join type (use EXPLAIN) is used.

Try changing the condition in the WHERE statement:

from

```sql
... p.id = 1 ...
```

to

```sql
... p.id > 0 ...
```

Another option is to use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute the query within the stored procedure.

Reported bug: [Bug #97097 Stored Procedure, JSON_TABLE and "const" join type](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97097).